# Default logging name for cassandra

Tags: logging, cassandra

I am trying to understand what is the default logging name for cassandra database shown by command nodetool getlogginglevels .
Under the logger name column I see listed the ROOT option and other two classes for which I don't know their functionality: com.thinkaurelius.thrift and org.apache.cassandra.
I need to know what is the default logging name for Cassandra in order to change it.

```
nodetool getlogginglevels

Logger Name                                        Log Level
ROOT                                                    INFO
com.thinkaurelius.thrift                               ERROR
org.apache.cassandra                                   DEBUG
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The `com.thinkaurelius.thrift` is for Graph-related components. And `org.apache.cassandra` should be for Cassandra itself...

and `ROOT` specifies default log for everything that isn't covered explicitly by other rules. See [logback architecture](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html) document for more details.

Comment: What about ROOT set to INFO ?

Comment: `ROOT` specifies default log for everything that isn't covered explicitly by other rules.